# Guidelines for user impression of a fast loading framework UI

Tags: angularjs, performance, user-interface, reactjs, user-experience

The actual loading time of a web page and the user impression of that loading time can be quite different. For example, here are three different experiences a user can have while a page loads:

- Waiting for a blank page to completely render at once
- Parts of the page immediately render (e.g. top navigation) but components load
  individually
- The entire page is made of components that load individually

These different UI experiences become more common as JavaScript frameworks become more common, such as React or Angular.

The user's UI experience can also change if individual components use loading markers to indicate something is happening, such as `Loading...` or a spinning wheel.

What are some guidelines for improving the user impression of a fast loading page? If there are not any, how do you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is always going to be an initial hit whilst the javascript gets parsed and executed.  However, if you are after very fast initial loads you could try a few techniques such as:

- Delivering a "critical" payload first which will quickly load the "essentials" of your webpage to make it feel much more responsive.  Webpack has a code splitting feature that you could use for this effect.
- Making use of Server Side Rendering (i.e. universal style applications) which will execute the javascript server side and embed the output in the HTML payload.  This probably renders the best results for what you are after as you don't getting the "flashing" parts as much you would otherwise.  It's a pretty cool technique but is probably presents more technical challenges so you will have to decide on your own tradeoffs.

If you are after an example of SSR you could look at a boilerplate I recently put together for React:  https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally

In that boilerplate I actually also make use of Webpack's code splitting feature based on the Routes defined within the application.  Checkout webpack's docs on this: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

If webpack is completely new to you I highly recommend the survive js series: https://survivejs.com/